# Mouse Over multiple transparent images stacked

Tags: php, javascript, html, transparency

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but I am trying to create an effect where when you mouse over an image that is the creation of multiple images overlapped with each other (images would be set with some opacity), I display that section of the image clearer than the other.

Hard to explain, but here a few examples

This image: [image]

is the creation of all those images overlapped (each image is on top of the previous)

[image]  [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]
[image]  [image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

When I mouse over the final image I want to be able to "highlight" the part of the image that corresponds to that section of the image in the image itself

Something I was thinking to do is to just show the main image with opaque set, when the user mouse over it, grab the coords, check against all of the images (that cannot be more than 25) see if those coordinates are matching with a non "transparent" pixel and display such image on top of the main to give an "highlighted" effect, but the final images are about 400x200 and create an array of all the pixels on the fly when displaying the page is not realistic for a server that have thousands of hits per hour/minutes.  Save this array in a database is not realistic as well as the size of the image might change depending on the page and we currently have 1.3milions final images each one being on average circa 10 broken down images

Comment: Are you looking to dynamically serve up a new image to every page visitor, or do you want to create each possible combination and choose the right one when they mouse over it?  First option = not a good idea, second option = not related to PHP.  I recommend removing that tag.

Comment: First option is what I have now.  Each visitor has different images set in their accounts, they can open the image and preview the final image as well as the various "sections". To change a section they have to click on the specific section.  What I want is for the end user to click on the part of the main image that they want to change and while they mouse over have such part "highlight"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abandoned the project, the ony solution is SVG but it nos possible at this stage as some browsers/OS do not support fully them

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to create custom SVG overlays for each sub-image. Upon an `onmouseover` event, you'd decrease the opacity of the SVG element, making the below image more visible.

Checkout [this](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html) tool for creating SVGs.

Comment: This is a good idea. Do you think that it will also be possible to change the "colors" of those elements ? You see each image is created on the fly dependent on some user values.  And what would you use to convert the various images into one SVG and then add the JS code for the mouseover ?

Comment: I need to create SVG on the fly, I am aware of the many tools out there to create SVG, as well as of tools to convert JPG into vector.

Comment: Not sure about creating SVGs on the fly. You can definitely change their color, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").css("opacity","0.8");

$("img").mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).css("opacity","1.0");
});

$("img").mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).css("opacity","0.8");
});
```

For the effect of segmenting the image, try using an image map:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml

Opacity of image maps is supported:

http://www.thehelper.net/threads/can-i-use-opacity-on-imagemap.57999/

**Edit**:

To achieve the hovering effect, try loading them into a canvas using Fabric JS, here is a demo:

http://fabricjs.com/hovering/

Comment: yes, that is how you do the opacity. Thank you.  My question is how do you recognize where in the image is the cursor located.  The images are all the same size, they simply have some pizels set as transparent.  JS doens't care what the pixel looks like, if you mouse over it only grab the image that is on top (I am planning to use overlapping DIVs with background-image)

Comment: @Fabrizio Edited. Image maps are compatible with old browsers BTW

Comment: I know, but how to create a map on the fly given a JPG (or PNG or GIF) ?

Comment: @Fabrizio I edited. You can load the images into a canvas, but this doesn't support older browsers. Anything that would support older browsers, would involve image processing in Javascript, which wouldn't be fun.

Comment: But again, this is one image at the time and when I hover over the transparent area that is above a different image it grabs the one on top.  I am pondering if maybe I should just create the pixel map with ranges and approximations and hopefully it won't cause too much lag in loading.  Will post my code if I can achieve it